# How to call a redux action outside of render method

Tags: react-native, redux

When I do this, the loginFromAPI method works as expected:

```
<Button onPress={this.props.loginFromAPI({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}) />
```

But when I do this, I see the console log, but loginFromAPI is not getting called.

```
login() {
   console.log("Test")
   this.props.loginFromAPI({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password})
}


<Button onPress={()=>this.login()} />
```

Comment: You don't post the rest of your code. But it would appear that your `login` method is not bound to the parent `Component` class. In your `constructor()` method, you'll want to do something like `this.login = this.login.bind(this)`. If it isn't bound to the `Component`, then it wouldn't have access to `this.props`.

Comment: Doesn't the arrow function automatically bind the method to the component class?

Comment: It does. But `this` in your class is just your class. You need to attach it to the parent class you're extending, as in `class myClass extends Component`. `this.props` is a member of `Component`, not `myClass`.

Comment: If you post your class declaration and your constructor (if there is one), I can show you.